# FlexSlider: strange carousel behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider

i'm using the latest version of FlexSlider.

The carousel doesnt work properly: when i click to the last visible thumb, the carousel is not scrolling to next thumbs. T

My JS code is:

```
    $('.switcher').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: true,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        itemWidth: 115,
        itemMargin: 2,
        move:1,
        slideshowSpeed: 1000,
        asNavFor: '.gallery-box'
    });

    $('.gallery-box').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 1000,
        directionNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: true,
        sync: ".switcher"
    });
```

HTML Code is exaclty like in official example: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Flexslider options: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties

My slider (LIVE, added autoanimation/1000ms to see the problem): http://ks.activemedia.pro/

Tried:

1. adding .resize() on start
2. adding style="width: 700px;" to parent div(s)
3. initialize slider on setTimeout() - to be sure that it isn't "DOM ready" problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that itemWidth is incorrect. It should be li's width + margins from both sides as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415736/set-the-amount-of-displaying-flex-slider-carousel-image).

Comment: Thanks. Well, i just decided to use fotorama.